# Set table field in SQL with local variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am attempting to update different fields in a destination table with a value from a source table. The update may be for different table column, which I am hoping to set dynamically.

It seems I cannot use "dest.[@FieldName]" to set the value dynamically. Is there a way for me to do this?

```
DECLARE @FieldName VARCHAR(50) = ''

SET @FieldName = 
   CASE
       WHEN @FieldCode = 0 THEN 'type'
       WHEN @FieldCode = 1 THEN 'name'
       WHEN @FieldCode = 2 THEN 'age'
   END

MERGE INTO DestTable dest
USING #tempTable src 
    ON dest.record_id = src.record_id
        WHEN MATCHED
            THEN UPDATE SET
                ***dest.[@FieldName]*** = src.value END;
```

Comment: In SQL, you can't parameterize identifiers. Also, Is there a reason why you're using `merge` instead of a simple `update`?

Comment: True, I probably don't need merge since I am not adding any new records to dest table.

Answer (score 1):

You always can use dynamic query. In this case you can also update all fields by condition:

```
MERGE INTO DestTable dest
USING #tempTable src 
ON dest.record_id = src.record_id
    WHEN MATCHED
        THEN UPDATE SET type = IIF(@FieldCode = 0, src.value, type),
                        name = IIF(@FieldCode = 1, src.value, name),
                        age = IIF(@FieldCode = 2, src.value, age)
```

Also you can use Dyanmic-Query:

```
DECLARE @Statement NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'MERGE INTO DestTable dest
USING #tempTable src 
ON dest.record_id = src.record_id
    WHEN MATCHED
        THEN UPDATE SET ' + IIF(@FieldCode = 0, 'type', IIF(@FieldCode = 1, 'name', 'age')) + ' = src.value'
EXEC(@Statement)
```

Comment: What you have is what I have coded for now, but it feels a bit wasteful to set all fields when I only need one field to be updated. Is there any way to act on only one @FieldCode and kick out?

Comment: You can use dynamic query.
https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-stored-procedures/sql-server-dynamic-sql/

Answer (score 0):

You can go for static query by going for IF ELSE logic.

```sql
IF @FieldCode = 0
BEGIN
UPDATE dest 
SET
type = src.value
FROM DestTable dest
INNER JOIN #tempTable src 
    ON dest.record_id = src.record_id
END 
ELSE IF @FieldCode = 1
BEGIN
UPDATE dest 
SET
name = src.value
FROM DestTable dest
INNER JOIN #tempTable src 
    ON dest.record_id = src.record_id
END
ELSE IF @FieldCode = 2
BEGIN
UPDATE dest 
SET
age = src.value
FROM DestTable dest
INNER JOIN #tempTable src 
    ON dest.record_id = src.record_id

end
```

Or you can have single UPDATE statement. based on `@fieldcode`, you are updating src.value, if different field code then, you are putting same value for UPDATE.

```sql
UPDATE dest 
SET
type = CASE WHEN @FieldCode = 0 THEN src.value ELSE dest.type END,
name = CASE WHEN @FieldCode = 1 THEN src.value ELSE dest.name END,
age = CASE WHEN @FieldCode = 2 THEN src.value ELSE dest.age END
FROM DestTable dest
INNER JOIN  #tempTable src 
    ON dest.record_id = src.record_id
```